# How to split string based on certain words

Tags: ruby, split

I want to split a string by `'START'` optionally surrounded by spaces. Examples:

```
params['body'] = 'START88'
# => command = 'START', service = '88'

params['body'] = 'START 88'
# => command = 'START', service = '88'
```

I tried:

```
command, service = params['body'].downcase.strip.split(' ')
```

but am not sure how to encompass words instead of spaces.

EDIT: Might I also add the service is not always numbers so it could quite easily be 'STARTSERVICE'. There are however a finite number of commands: START, STOP, SUB, UNSUB.

Comment: Show some example input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` with named captures, for example:

```
example_arr = ['START88', 'START 88', 'start 88', 'STOP 99']
matcher = /(?<command>start|stop)\s*(?<service>\d*)/i
example_arr.map { |line| line.match matcher }

#=> [#<MatchData "START88" command:"START" service:"88">, 
     #<MatchData "START 88" command:"START" service:"88">, 
     #<MatchData "start 88" command:"start" service:"88">, 
     #<MatchData "STOP 99" command:"STOP" service:"99">]
```

It's just example, in your case it would be something like:

```
params['body'] = 'START88'
command, service = params['body'].match(matcher).captures

> command
#=> "START"
> service
#=> "88"
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend here. Just pass the words you want to split on (Stop for example) and you can also use `i` so you don't need to downcase:

```
command, service = params['body'].split(/(stop)/i)
```

A better example:

```
words = %w(stop start)
your_string = 'stop88 start 88'

your_string.gsub!(/\s+/, "") # remove whitespaces
your_string.split(/(#{words.join('|')})/i).reject(&:empty?)
=> ["stop", "88", "start", "88"]
```

`/(#{words.join('|')})/i` translates to `/(stop|start)/i` in this example

- takes an array of words that you want to split on and joins them with `|` meaning it'll match either of them
- applies `()` to include the matches themselves.
- `/i` means it's case-insensitive
- `reject(&:empty?)` just deletes empty fields if any

Comment: Consider using [`Regexp#union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-union) instead of `(#{words.join('|')})`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Makes it harder to add case-insensitive modifier. This `/#{ Regexp.union(words).source }/i` looks more complex than `/(#{words.join('|')})/i` in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
['START88', 'START 88'].map { |w| w.scan(/(\w+)\s*(\d+)/) }
#⇒ [['START', '88'], ['START', '88']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given string you can also extract digits and letters *without regexes*.

```
a = "START88"
a.chars.select{|e| e.chr.to_i != 0 }.join("")
#=> "88"
# you can also use reject if != is not for you -))
#a.chars.select{ |e| e.chr.to_i != 0 }.join("").to_i
#=> 88
a.chars.select{ |e| e.chr.to_i == 0 }.join("")
#=> "START"
```

p.s. converting a string into an array, then joining elements to form a string is not a good solution, but in case if you hate regexes -))